# Best way to do sql delete of data when looping through a set

Tags: sql

I've got a set of about 200 000 id's stored in a set, I want to loop through the set and do a DELETE from a table where the id's in the table match the id's in the set.

At the moment I'm just doing this as I loop through:

```
for(Integer i : idList) {
    sql = "delete from sdata where id = " + i
    stmtDelete.executeUpdate(sqlDelete);
}
```

My question is would it be worthwhile for me to use a prepared statement in this case and do a

```
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

as I loop through the set ?
Or is there a more better/efficient way?

Thanks.

Comment: You could do a function to concat the conditions connected by OR under WHERE clause and do the deletion in 1 submit. I do this all the time :)

Comment: Cant you use where id in the_list_of_ids_here???

Comment: I think including your idList in a prepared statement would probably perform best. Doing what Gordon suggests still requires you to insert 200k records, before performing the deletion. eg WHERE id IN ...idList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

200,000 ids are a large number of ids.  I would insert them into a table and do something like:

```
delete from sdata
    where id in (select id from TempList)
```

Note:  in some SQL engines, `exists` with a correlated subquery performs better than an `in`.

This is a large number of deletes, which will fill a lot of log space and lock the table for a while.  You may want to do them in smaller increments, such as 10,000 at a time.